# Using Handlebars for templating other than HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, intellij-idea, handlebars.js

I like how simple Handlebars is and how its design encourages the user to not put logic into the view.  I have used it to template things other than HTML, but I am noticing the Handlebars.js website only discusses HTML examples.  Is Handlebars only for templating HTML?

My IDE IntelliJ also only syntax checks/highlights my Handlebars files as HTML.  I was hoping renaming my handlebars files with the intended extension as secondary (like Question.xml.hbs) would clue IntelliJ into my intentions, but it continued processing like I was editing HTML.  There do not appear to be any pragmas in Handlebars for me to indicate what my target format or MIME type should be.

Architecturally, is it bad form to use Handlebars for purposes other than HTML templating?  What if I restrict myself to HTML-like languages, like XML?

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars is used mostly with HTML. But you can change template language for a specified file in the IDEA settings. See:

[image]

**Update:**
In the settings you can specify a template language to whole project.

Comment: Cool screenshot!  I think this underscores the awesomeness of IntelliJ and the jillions of point integrations they do for the developer.  Unfortunately, I think their approach is not appropriate and not useful.  There either needs to be an official pragma in the Handlebars language that IDE vendors can observe for syntax parsing, or there needs to be a de facto convention of a pragma in a Handlebars comment that the IDE vendors can observe.  In any case, the Handlebars maintainers need to specify this.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Anyway if you see how another approach can be implemented please file an issue  tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: Thanks for the update, good observation regarding making project-level settings.  Yep, already done posting a change request on the bug tracker.  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14225